# Standalone web app HTML table for Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make a standalone web app that's an interface for a Google Sheet -- not *any* Google Sheet, but *one specific* Google sheet.

Essentially, let's just assume that I have a google sheet with an employee directory on it, and I want a direct link to show a plain-jane HTML table of the data. Everywhere I've looked doesn't seem to cover this in this way, so I'm very confused.

Comment: You don't mention whether you want it to be interactive or not ...?

Comment: My eventual goal is to have a simple sortable table with 4-5 of the columns in my spreadsheet, and clicking on a row brings up a profile with all the columns -- a basic employee directory and profile. I wrote a simple script in python to convert my spreadsheet to JSON and had no troubles building the html/js to do above, but I can't figure out how to do it in a way that's bound directly to the google sheet with live updates